# Socket IO 1.2 Query Parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I can't figure out how to retrieve query parameters on the server side for socket.io
1.2.1

Here's my client side code

```
 var socket = io('http://localhost:3000/',{_query:"sid=" + $('#sid').attr('data-sid') + "&serial=" + $('#serial_tracker').text()});
```

and the server side:

```
io.use(function(socket,next){  //find out if user is logged in
        var handshake = socket.request;
        console.log(socket.request._query);
        handshake.sid = handshake.query.sid;
}
```

socket.request._query is:

```
{ EIO: '3', transport: 'polling', t: '1419909065555-0' }
```

Does anyone know how query parameters work in socket io 1.2.1?
Thanks for any help and if you need any more information, just ask me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When sending handshake query data to socket.io, use the following property name in the object:

```
{
  query: 'token=12345'
}
```

I see above you used `_query` for a property name instead.

You should be able to access the query information at socket.request._query at that point. I'm not sure if there is a better way to get a hold of that data? I'm guessing yes, since they put an underscore in front of it, but I haven't found a better way yet.

Here's the full example of a connect query that is working for me (forgive the formatting, I'm copy/pasting this out of different node modules into an inline solution).

Server (using socket 1.2.1 nodejs):

```
var restify = require('restify');
var api = restify.createServer();
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var io = socketio.listen(api.server); // api is an instance of restify, listening on localhost:3000
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    // socket.request._query.token is accessible here, for me, and will be '12345'
    next();
});
api.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', api.name, api.url);
});
```

Client (chrome browser using the client library located at https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.1.js):

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/', { query: 'token=12345' });
```

Comment: When I tried this, it didn't even connect. That's why I changed it to _query

Comment: Interesting. I'll update my answer with the full code I'm using.